# Check if a value exist before trying to display it Angular 4

Tags: angular

I'm on a project using Angular 4.

I'm using a code like this :

```
<div *ngFor="let item of results">
 <p> {{item.location.city}} </p>
 <p> {{item.location.country}} </p>
</div>
```

To show some results from a json i get with a request.

The problem is that my BDD is not well constructed and sometime, there is no location. As soon as there is a problem with a value, the rest of the result stop to display, which is a bit annoying.

Is there a way to check if the value exist, and if it's the case let angular show it. I try with ngIf but got the same problem as angular try to see if there is a value and if not stop the ngfor.

You can see the problem in live here : http://yunomusic.com/page-search-event (try with paris as city ad scroll down you will see this : 
[image: problem screenshot]

and the error i got from console :

```
vendor.fa8737033d56bf5e7c33.bundle.js:17 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'city' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (e.ngfactory.js:163)
    at Object.updateDirectives (vendor.fa8737033d56bf5e7c33.bundle.js:136)
    at ur (vendor.fa8737033d56bf5e7c33.bundle.js:136)
    at wr (vendor.fa8737033d56bf5e7c33.bundle.js:136)
    at br (vendor.fa8737033d56bf5e7c33.bundle.js:136)
    at ur (vendor.fa8737033d56bf5e7c33.bundle.js:136)
    at wr (vendor.fa8737033d56bf5e7c33.bundle.js:136)
    at br (vendor.fa8737033d56bf5e7c33.bundle.js:136)
    at ur (vendor.fa8737033d56bf5e7c33.bundle.js:136)
    at wr (vendor.fa8737033d56bf5e7c33.bundle.js:136)
```

angular try to read the component city but on some element in my BDD i don't have one. I need to check before showing.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add *ngIf="item.location" to your p tags

Comment: Thank you, effectively i was trying with *ngIf="item.location.place", but with item.location it worked !

Answer (score 10):

Better solution will be simply using **`safe navigation operator`** without **`ng-if`** in this case,

```
<div *ngFor="let item of results">
 <p> {{item?.location?.city}} </p>
 <p> {{item?.location?.country}} </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Would that still render the p tags? If not, then this is heaps better

Comment: yeah, try and see

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  Especially if you are using ngFor, if the HTML element like p or td is not rendered, it's a nightmare to get the formatting right.